# Active directory search for all groups and users matching a particular name in c# using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement?

Tags: c#, active-directory

It seems *System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement* provides query by example which can only search one type of object at a time.

Does *System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement* proves a method using which I can search entire active directory for users or groups matching a particular name or some other criteria or I have to go back to *System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be able to do this in S.DS.AM. Both the `UserPrincipal` as well as the `GroupPrincipal` ultimately descend from `Principal` - so if you pass in a "generic" principal to the searcher, you should get back both users and groups (and computers).

The only tricky part is that `Principal` is an abstract class, so you cannot directly instantiate it - you need to get a `UserPrincipal` first and "extract" the generic `Principal` from that:

```
// set up dummy UserPrincipal
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

// get the generic Principal from that - set the "Name" to search for
Principal userOrGroup = qbeUser as Principal;
userOrGroup.Name = "SomeName";

// create a PrincipalSearcher based on that generic principal
PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userOrGroup);

// enumerate the results - you need to check what kind of principal you get back
foreach (Principal found in searcher.FindAll())
{
    // is it a UserPrincipal - do what you need to do with that...
    if (found is UserPrincipal)
    {
        ......
    }
    else if (found is GroupPrincipal)
    {
        // if it's a group - do whatever you need to do with a group....
    }
 }
```